# Clipboard listening outside of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clipboard, chrome-native-messaging

Is it possible to listen to the host OS clipboard from a Chrome extension for each "insert" event (STRG+C or from context menu), to inspect the copied content?

**Background:** If a value from another application is copied into the clipboard, I want to check that copied value against certain regular expressions to identify a specific website the value might associated with, so I can immediately open a new tab with the website this value belongs too.

Is this only possible through an additional application running on the host, that is listening and sending data to the Chrome extension by native messaging?

Comment: You can check the clipboard periodically. The extension will need `clipboardRead` permission.

Comment: But is this the host's clipboard or Chrome's sandboxed one? Or did I misunderstood the clipboard scope?

Comment: No idea. In Windows there's only one clipboard.